# Summary statistics for bipartite networks

Tags: references, descriptive-statistics, large-data, graph-theory, networks

I have a large bipartite network that I would like to summarise. So far, I have found the following summary statistics:

- Degree centrality
- Graph density
- Modularity
- Nestedness

I have not found a textbook or review that presents commonly used summary statistics in the analysis of bipartite networks. Does such a summary exist? Could you recommend any other summary statistics that could be useful?